# How to use where clause with ORDER BY in sqlite iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I have table from which i want that it should fetch data by desc views but where cluase using here is the query it does not return any thing.

```
                 select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster WHERE ContentTagText ORDER BY Views DESC ='%@'",appDelegate.tagInput];
```

If remove where clause then it shows data in desc.

Comment: Did you check you correct table column names from your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to restructure your query, you mixed up the ORDER BY and WHERE clauses. It should look something like this:

```
NSString *select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ContentMaster WHERE ContentTagText = '%@' ORDER BY Views", appDelegate.tagInput];
```

I don't know the exact names of your columns, so you might need to adjust that. But basically the filter (= '%@') needs to be in the WHERE clause, the ORDER BY clause contains the column by which the result is sorted.